# SWI-Prolog: Looking for a way to print dictionary values in seperate lines

Tags: dictionary, swi-prolog

I am searching a way to print some [dictionary](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) values in a way every value is on a separate line in the terminal.

For example if I have

```
X = abc{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:10}.
```

The output itself is:

```
?- X = abc{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:10}.
X = abc{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10}.
```

For purpose of clarity my aim now is to get the following output:

```
X = abc{
a:1, 
b:2, 
c:3, 
d:4, 
e:5, 
f:6, 
g:7, 
h:8, 
i:9, 
j:10
}.
```

or alternatively simple

```
a:1
b:2 
c:3 
d:4
e:5 
f:6
g:7 
h:8 
i:9 
j:10
```

Is their a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide a custom [`portray/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=portray/1) hook for dictionaries. As an example:

```
portray(Term) :-
    is_dict(Term),
    dict_pairs(Term, Tag, Pairs),
    writef("%p{\n", [Tag]),
    foreach(member(Key-Value, Pairs), writef("\t%p: %p\n", [Key, Value])),
    write("}").
```

This will also work on nested terms (though more care could be added to indent nested terms correctly). Example output:

```
?- X = abc{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:foo{bar:10, baz:11}}.
X = abc{
        a: 1
        b: 2
        c: 3
        d: 4
        e: 5
        f: 6
        g: 7
        h: 8
        i: 9
        j: foo{
        bar: 10
        baz: 11
}
}.
```

If the [`portray/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=portray/1) hook is not already enabled for answers to the terminal (it was for me) you may need to adjust the [`answer_write_options`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags) flag.

Comment: Thanks portray(abc{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:foo{bar:10, baz:11}}) gives false. How exactly can I activate it or set the flag in console?

Comment: By default there aren't going to be any `portray/1` definitions which is likely why it returns false. Querying `listing(portray/1).` can confirm that. When prolog tries to "print" something it will first try to call `portray/1` if you add the portray example above to your code or assert it interactively in the terminal, it will be used when printing dictionaries and you should see the output above.

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, and you were asking how to add the example from the console, see the third example from the docs here, note how when using `assert` the rule has extra parenthesis around it: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1